# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]': for 'Add to App' flutter app with firebase_crashlytics

Tags: flutter, crashlytics, flutter-add-to-app

**TLDR;**

How can we configure firebase crashlytics with flutterfire for [Add to App](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app)
I've seen other stackoverflow questions and tried those options already

**Longer version:**

- Parent app, doesn't have any firebase plugins nor firebase.initialize() calls. It just refers to the child package app
- In the child app we have fire base plugins and initialize calls.
- If you are curious about our setup, its on [medium](https://medium.com/@satyajit/running-integration-tests-as-part-of-mrs-for-add-to-app-flutter-apps-75bdd0823a45).
- In child's main.dart file we have the following code

```
    void main() {
      runZonedGuarded(() async {
        // Initialize Flutter bindings; must come first!
        WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
        await Firebase.initializeApp(
        );
        ...
```

Call stack looks like this

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
#0      MethodChannelFirebase.app (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:193:5)
#1      Firebase.app (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:53:41)
#2      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance (package:firebase_crashlytics/src/firebase_crashlytics.dart:33:55)
#3      main.<anonymous closure> (package:package/main.dart:58:25)
#4      _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1450:47)
#5      _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1342:19)
#6      runZonedGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1832:18)
#7      _Zone._processUncaughtError (dart:async/zone.dart:1109:14)
#8      _CustomZone.handleUncaughtError (dart:async/zone.dart:1312:5)
#9      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:16)
#10     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:574:5)
#11     _completeOnAsync<…>
```

All was well with firebase 1.5.0 but I had to upgrade for crashlytics

Change in packages
[image]

So far what I have tried

1. Generate the file firebase_options.dart file from flutterconfigure and refer to it from the child with following syntax

```
 await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
```

2. Also tried to give `name` parameter but that didn't help either.

Question is where is the [DEFAULT] project being referenced and how can I remove/edit it?

Comment: you can follow the manual firebase setup process. You need to add firebase to android, ios, and web manually. you can follow this documentation for that -> https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue should be fixed with the latest version of [firebase_core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core/changelog) and any additional flutterfire packages you might be using in your project.